How to get column names from JSON file in Apache Drill
I am trying to work with JSON files validation using Apache Drill. I am working with both linear and nested JSON data. I have stored the JSON file in Drill tmp storage dfs/tmp/employee_src_reg_json.json. The JSON data inside the file looks like this:
{
  "employee_reg": [
    {
      "EmployeeID": 1,
      "FirstName": "John",
      "LastName": "Doe",
      "Age": 35,
      "Salary": 60000,
      "Department": "Engineering",
      "Experience": 8
    },
    {
      "EmployeeID": 2,
      "FirstName": "Jane",
      "LastName": "",
      "Age": 28,
      "Salary": 50000,
      "Department": "Marketing",
      "Experience": 5
    },
    {
      "EmployeeID": 3,
      "FirstName": "Michael",
      "LastName": "Johnson",
      "Age": 40,
      "Salary": 70000,
      "Department": "Finance",
      "Experience": 12
    },
    {
      "EmployeeID": 4,
      "FirstName": "Emily",
      "LastName": "Williams",
      "Age": 32,
      "Salary": 65000,
      "Department": "Human Resources",
      "Experience": 9
    }
  ]
}


I need a query to get the column names in Apache Drill. I tried the following queries but did not get the column names:
1)DESCRIBE dfs/tmp/employee_src_reg_json.json - this gives no data available.
2)DESCRIBE (SELECT * FROM (SELECT FLATTEN(t.employee_reg) AS emp FROM dfs.tmp.employee_src_reg_json.json t) LIMIT 1) - this gives the first JSON array values but not the column names.
3)(SELECT FLATTEN(t.employee_reg) AS flatdata FROM dfs.tmp.employee_src_reg_json.json t) - this gives something like:
00-00    Screen
00-01      Project(flatdata=[$0])
00-02        Flatten(flattenField=[$0])
00-03          Project(flatdata=[$0])
00-04            Scan(table=[[dfs, tmp, employee_src_reg_json.json]], groupscan=[EasyGroupScan [selectionRoot=file:/tmp/employee_src_reg_json.json, numFiles=1, columns=[employee_reg], files=[file:/tmp/employee_src_reg_json.json], usedMetastore=false, limit=-1, formatConfig=JSONFormatConfig [extensions=[json]]]])
{
  "head" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "generator" : {
      "type" : "ExplainHandler",
      "info" : ""
    }
  }


4)SHOW COLUMNS IN (SELECT FLATTEN(t.employee_reg) FROM dfs.tmp.employee_src_reg_json.json t);
How can I get the column names from the JSON file?

I don't know Apache Drill, but the column names are not the keys of the map of each list item ?

Try this:
SELECT getMapSchema(record) AS schema FROM dfs.test.`schema_test.json`;

